# FInding the path where Visual Studio is Installed

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

How I can find the path where Microsoft visual Studio is installed. I need to use that path in my program.

What is the function that has to be called or what other method can I use to get the path where Microsoft Visual Studio is installed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the app, it's probably best to ask the user, but here's some C# code that should do the trick for VS2008.

```
RegistryKey regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Setup\VS");
string vsInstallationPath = regKey.GetValue("ProductDir").ToString();
regKey.Close();
```

Answer (score 6):

It is probably possible to find it by searching the registry, but as I wanted a solution for build scripts I have been using environment variables to do this.

N.B. The name of the environment variable to query is version specific.

For VS2005 you can use VS80COMNTOOLS

For VS2008 you can use VS90COMNTOOLS

If you type SET VS90COMNTOOLS at a command prompt you should see:
VS90COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\

so go up two folders to get to the root of the install path.

Answer (score 2):

This is the quickest way to know the folder where VS is installed or any other program.

Open VS code and when it is running; open the **Windows Task Manager** and navigate to the **Details tab**.

Right-click on the Code.exe application that should be running by now and choose the option to **Open File Location**:

**Windows Task Manager** > **Details Tab** > RIGHTCLICK **Code.exe** > **Open File Location**

[image]

Comment: OP was asking for Visual Studio, not VSCode

Answer (score 1):

From the registry, HKLM\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\InstallDir for Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 1):

**For newer versions of VS it is better to use by Microsoft provided APIs, because install information is no longer maintained in registry correctly.**

1. install Nuget package **Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Configuration.Interop**
2. do the trick (returned is tuple with version and path of all VS instances):

   ```
    private const int REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG = unchecked((int)0x80040154);

    public static IEnumerable<(string, string)> GetVisualStudioInstallPaths() 
    {
        var result = new List<(string, string)>();

        try
        {
            var query = new SetupConfiguration() as ISetupConfiguration2;
            var e = query.EnumAllInstances();

            int fetched;
            var instances = new ISetupInstance[1];

            do
            {
                e.Next(1, instances, out fetched);

                if (fetched > 0)
                {
                    var instance2 = (ISetupInstance2)instances[0];
                    result.Add((instance2.GetInstallationVersion(), instance2.GetInstallationPath()));
                }
            }
            while (fetched > 0);
        }
        catch (COMException ex) when (ex.HResult == REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)
        {
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        return result;
    }
   ```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Is this for an add-in of some sort for Visual Studio?

Because otherwise, you need to be aware that someone running your program may not actually *have* Visual Studio installed.

If it *is* installed, you can generally find it at a known location in the registry, such as `HKCR/Applications/devenv.exe/shell/edit/command` for VS2008.